# While airflow initdb, AttributeError: module' object has no attribute 'client_auth'

Tags: python-2.7, airflow

I have recently installed apache airflow 1.8.1, I executed following command:

`airflow initdb`

which returned following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/airflow", line 18, in <module>
    from airflow.bin.cli import CLIFactory
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 65, in <module>
    auth=api.api_auth.client_auth)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'client_auth'
```

I tried several solutions but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I figured out what we were doing wrong. The field `auth_backend=airflow.contrib.auth.backends.password_auth` needs to be under `webserver` and not under `api`. Add it if it is not already there. There are multiple fields for `auth_backend` as there are `authenticate` etc..

Comment: This worked for me. It was confusing when I saw these fields in multiple places but this makes sense now. Just fill it out under webserver.

Comment: The documentation isn't clear. I also got confused by the same setting under `api`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with airflow 1.8.1 with python 2.7.11.

I have disabled the webserver auth ( temporarily) and  switched to the default value for auth_backend. ( that solved the issue)

The final configuration in my airflow.cfg is as follows

auth_backend = airflow.api.auth.backend.default

authenticate = False

Comment: What if I want to enable authentication? I can't seem to find a work around for this :(